# Rendering Alpha Channel Video Over Background (AVFoundation, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Recently, I have been following [this](https://medium.com/@quentinfasquel/ios-transparent-video-with-coreimage-52cfb2544d54) tutorial, which has taught me how to play a video with alpha channel in iOS.  This has been working great to build an `AVPlayer` over something like a `UIImageView`, which allows me to make it look like my video (with the alpha channel removed) is playing on top of the image.

Using this approach, I now need to find a way to do this while rendering/saving the video to the user's device.  This is my code to generate the alpha video that plays in the `AVPlayer`;

```
let videoSize = CGSize(width: playerItem.presentationSize.width, height: playerItem.presentationSize.height / 2.0)

let composition = AVMutableVideoComposition(asset: playerItem.asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in
   let sourceRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: videoSize)
   let alphaRect = sourceRect.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: sourceRect.height)
   let filter = AlphaFrameFilter()
   filter.inputImage = request.sourceImage.cropped(to: alphaRect)
                .transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -sourceRect.height))
   filter.maskImage = request.sourceImage.cropped(to: sourceRect)
   return request.finish(with: filter.outputImage!, context: nil)
```

(That's been truncated a bit for ease, but I can confirm this approach properly returns an `AVVideoComposition` that I can play in `AVPlayer`.

I recognize that I can use an `AVVideoComposition` with an `AVExportSession`, but this only allows me to render my alpha video over a black background (and not an image or video, as I'd need).

Is there a way to overlay the now "background-removed" alpha channel, on top of another video and process out?